Java код ошибки 415
Проблема в том, что если явно не указать contentType, то приходит ошибка 415, на монолите такой проблемы нет, код идентичный

Дело в том, что при отправке запроса, в запросе могут хранится разные типы данных. По умолчанию ajax, считает, что это application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, в Вашем случае это не так, потому что на бэке указано ожидание json @Consumes("application/json"), укажите в параметрах ajax верный формат. Что-то вроде этого:
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    global: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    // ...


Архитектура Вашего приложения не должна влиять на это, высока вероятность что дело в настройках сервера с серисами, скоро всего в монолите он автоматом валидировал запросы в нужный формат.

Да, это понятно, но неужели это касается только микросервисной архитектуры? На монолите подобной проблемы не встречается. Интересно просто узнать первопричину
